# Can I Use Macros When Recording Audio in Adobe Premiere?

Tags: premiere, automation

Every time I record audio on the timeline in Adobe Premiere, I have to do three things for all recordings:

1. Add the right hand side audio channel as my microphone is mono.
2. Increase the DB to 4.4.
3. Add in a sound preset effect.

I'm sure I'm not utilising Premiere properly and that there has to be a way to automate these three things whenever I record audio?

An example of me doing these three things, that I would like automated is below: